# Use hook to force specific format of git commit message

Tags: git, pre-commit-hook

I want to use a git hook to force commit messages to comply with a specific format (they should end with #number). I've tried installing [this hook](http://progit.org/book/ch7-4.html), also referenced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7153927/git-hook-for-legit-commit-message-123-good-message), but I keep getting the message:

```
$ git commit -am "Test"
.git/hooks/commit-msg: line 1: sage_file: command not found
.git/hooks/commit-msg: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `('
.git/hooks/commit-msg: line 2: `message = File.read(message_file)'
```

I'm using the scripts exactly as they appear in the examples, and both give the same error. I have tried for instance:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
message_file = ARGV[0]
message = File.read(message_file)

#starts with # then number, space, and at least 5 words no more than 200
$regex = /(^#[0-9]+ \W*(\w+(\W+|$)){5,200})/

if !$regex.match(message)
puts "Your message is not formatted correctly (example: #XXX at least 5 words)"
exit 1
end
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: Can you post the contents of the *actual* script that you're using? We don't know whether you've changed anything from what is published in Pro Git.

Comment: Is it possible that (a) you're doing this on Windows, and (b) you've accidentally introduced Windows CRLF line endings into your script? Shell scripts don't like those. It is also suspicious that your error message says it can't find `sage_file` but your script doesn't specifically refer to that.

Comment: Yes, great insight! It was not Windows but vim that somehow messed up the linebreaks, apparently, but it is solved by saving it using another editor. Thanks! If you could put this as an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible that (a) you're doing this on Windows, and (b) you've accidentally introduced Windows CRLF line endings into your script. Shell scripts don't like those, and can cause the sort of problem you observe.

To set Vim to write Unix-style LF line endings, use

```
:set ff=unix
:w
```