# How do I set a pattern for git commit messages?

Tags: git

I want to restrict the people whoever commits to have a specific commit message format, how do I do that?

For example: `Pair_Name|Story_Number|Commit_Message`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a `pre-commit-msg` or `commit-msg` hook, that you could use:

- http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/githooks.html

Git repos come with sample hooks, e.g. the sample `commit-msg` hook under `git/hooks/commit-msg.sample` catches duplicate Signed-off-by lines.

```
# This example catches duplicate Signed-off-by lines.

test "" = "$(grep '^Signed-off-by: ' "$1" |
    sort | uniq -c | sed -e '/^[   ]*1[    ]/d')" || {
    echo >&2 Duplicate Signed-off-by lines.
    exit 1
}
```

To enable a hook, don't forget to make it executable.

---

Here's some fictional example, which would only accept commit messages of the `london|120|something ...` and the like:

```rb
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
message_file = ARGV[0]
message = File.read(message_file)

# $regex = /\[ref: (\d+)\]/

PAIRS = ["london", "paris", "moscow"] # only these names allowed
STORIES = "\d{2,4}"                   # story must be a 2, 3 or 4 digit number
MESSAGE = ".{5,}"                     # message must be at least 5 chars long

$regex = "( (#{PAIRS.join('|')})\|#{STORIES}\|#{MESSAGE} )"

if !$regex.match(message)
  puts "[POLICY] Your message is not formatted correctly"
  exit 1
end
```

In usage:

```rb
$ git ci -m "berlin|120"
[POLICY] Your message is not formatted correctly
$ git ci -m "london|120|XX"    
[POLICY] Your message is not formatted correctly
$ git ci -m "london|120|Looks good."    
[master 853e622] london|120|Looks good.
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
```

Answer (score 1):

Note: this kind of restriction is part of [gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite) as well (an [authorization layer](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/auth.html) that allows all sort of checks when pushing to a repo)

You can see one example at "[git gitolite (v3) `pre-receive` hook for all commit messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13087625/git-gitolite-v3-pre-receive-hook-for-all-commit-messages)".

The idea with gitolite is that you can easily deploy that hook on specific repos, for specific groups of users.