# How do I enforce the 50 character commit summary line in Sublime?

Tags: git, sublimetext, commit

As a naturally talkative soul, my summary lines almost always exceed 50 characters.  How do I enforce a 50 character limit on my title lines in sublime for commit messages and commit messages only?  Is there a way to customize the settings?

Comment: you could create an after commit hook to enforce it, but is it really worth it?

Comment: A *pre*-commit hook seems like the way to go. An after (*post*-) commit hook cannot enforce anything.

Comment: Congrats on keeping your question's text brief :)

Comment: You could use an editor which supports this, such as emacs and the Git-Commit minor mode.

Comment: Remark: This can be done in `git` directly with `commit-msg` hook, refer to  [How do I set a pattern for git commit messages?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14151775/5267751) .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A plugin like [sublime-text-git](https://github.com/kemayo/sublime-text-git) would impose a [soft wrap on git commit message](https://github.com/kemayo/sublime-text-git/blob/master/Git%20Commit%20Message.sublime-settings):

```
{
  "rulers": [70]
}
```

But that applies to all the lines, not just the first one.

You could modify that plugin to change colors when you type (but that would require some python programming); this is what [an editor like vim does](http://kparal.wordpress.com/2011/08/03/git-tip-of-the-day-syntax-highlighting-for-commit-messages/):

[image: http://kparal.files.wordpress.com/2011/08/git-vim-commit.png?w=595]

Remember that for previous lengthy message, you can view them with the appropriate length through a LESS option. See "[How to wrap git commit comments?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4345265/6309)".

---

Otherwise, as [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21641085/how-do-i-enforce-the-50-character-commit-summary-line-in-sublime/21643784#comment32706281_21641085) by [larsks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/147356/larsks), a [`commit-msg` hook like this one](http://addamhardy.com/2013/06/05/good-commit-messages-and-enforcing-them-with-git-hooks.html) (from **[Addam Hardy](http://addamhardy.com/)**, in python) is the only solution to really *enforce* that policy.

```python
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys, os
from subprocess import call

print os.environ.get('EDITOR')

if os.environ.get('EDITOR') != 'none':
  editor = os.environ['EDITOR']
else:
  editor = "vim"

message_file = sys.argv[1]

def check_format_rules(lineno, line):
    real_lineno = lineno + 1
    if lineno == 0:
        if len(line) > 50:
            return "Error %d: First line should be less than 50 characters " \
                    "in length." % (real_lineno,)
    if lineno == 1:
        if line:
            return "Error %d: Second line should be empty." % (real_lineno,)
    if not line.startswith('#'):
        if len(line) > 72:
            return "Error %d: No line should be over 72 characters long." % (
                    real_lineno,)
    return False


while True:
    commit_msg = list()
    errors = list()
    with open(message_file) as commit_fd:
        for lineno, line in enumerate(commit_fd):
            stripped_line = line.strip()
            commit_msg.append(line)
            e = check_format_rules(lineno, stripped_line)
            if e:
                errors.append(e)
    if errors:
        with open(message_file, 'w') as commit_fd:
            commit_fd.write('%s\n' % '# GIT COMMIT MESSAGE FORMAT ERRORS:')
            for error in errors:
                commit_fd.write('#    %s\n' % (error,))
            for line in commit_msg:
                commit_fd.write(line)
        re_edit = raw_input('Invalid git commit message format.  Press y to edit and n to cancel the commit. [y/n]')
        if re_edit.lower() in ('n','no'):
            sys.exit(1)
        call('%s %s' % (editor, message_file), shell=True)
        continue
    break
```

Comment: The right hook to check the message is `commit-msg`, not `pre-commit`; that's what the linked blog post uses.